# Using a dot in the selection (D3.js)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I found a lot of code that uses a dot inside the bracket like this:

`var node = svg.selectAll(".circles")`.

Can someone help me with an explanation of that dot?­­­­­

Thanks

Comment: its a way of selecting class. (here ^^ `circles` is a class)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`svg.selectAll(".circles")` will select all elements in your SVG that have the class `circles`. So the `.` is basically to specify you want to select based on classname.

Doing something like `svg.selectAll("circle")` will select all `circle` elements inside your `svg`. This is based on the name inside the tag. For example if you have the following code below, it will select both circles.

```
<svg>
  <circle></circle>
  <circle></circle>
</svg>
```

Another example to explain a little better:

Lets say we have the following code

```
<svg> 
    <g class="red"></g>
    <g class="blue"></g>
</svg>
```

In the case above, if I do `svg.selectAll(".red")`, I will select the first `g` element because it has the class name `red`.

However, If I do `svg.selectAll("g")`, it will select both `g` elements and not worry about class name. This type of filtering without the `.` is solely based on the name of the element.

Comment: Thanks, what is the difference when i use `svg.selectAll("circles")`? That means without the dot?

Comment: So to make it clearly: when you wanna select classes, then use `.`. When you wanna use elements, that are not classes, then leave the `.` out?

Comment: I think you're confusing elements and classes. Let me explain further in the answer.